# Pass for loop item to prop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How do you pass the item instance from the foreach loop as a prop?

```
<div v-for="n in parentArray">
  <blog-card prop="{{ n.content }}"></blog-card>
</div>
```

When I run this I get an error

> (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)

Can this be done without rebinding the item to the parent component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Vue 2 you don't use interpolation in attributes, you use the [attribute binding syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes).

```
<blog-card v-bind:prop="n.content"></blog-card>
```

Or the shortcut

```
<blog-card :prop="n.content"></blog-card>
```